# Populating a select menu with mysql values in node.js, express and jade

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, pug

I am new to node.js, i want to know how to populate a select menu on page load with mysql values. I am using nodejs, expressjs and jade/pug. I am unable to find any solution in google.

Jade file:-

```
block sale
 form(action = "/get_sale", method = "GET")
  select(id="cbosale", name="cbosale", class="custom-select custom-select-sm")
   each sale in ["24", "34"]
    option(value="#{sale}") #{sale}
```

App.js file:-

```
app.get('/get_sale', function(req, res){
 db.connect(function(err){
  db.query("SELECT DISTINCT(SaleNo), Season FROM tcatalogue",function(err, result, fields){
  Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key){
    var row = result[key];
    console.log(row.SaleNo)
  })
})
})
})
```

Instead of the static values in the jade file, values should be fetched from the app.js file.

Comment: Would be good if you can show us the HTML that you are already using and also how you obtain the value from mysql server.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help pages [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to get the route you need to fire a select query on your database and send the data to pug along with render as:

```
app.get('/output',function(req,res,next){
   con.query("SELECT * FROM tableName", function (err, result, fields) 
    {
    if (err) 
      throw err; 
    else
      res.render('output',{page_title:"Output",data:result}); 
   }); 
 });
```

Now your `output.pug` page will be produced with the data which you can populate them as options for your select menu.

```
html
    head
        title= 'Output'
    body
      select
        each variable in data
        option(value=variable.saleNo)
```

Indent the code properly in pug.

Comment: Thank you, now i understood the route part, but how to populate the select menu in the jade template with the values. Sorry, i am completely new to this.

Comment: I added basic format how data can be populated to select menu. Change it accordingly. Hope it might help you.

Comment: Happy that i could help you.